# EF code first foreign key ignored, getting "Invalid column name"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a fairly simple class which holds potential types of users:

```
public class Core_UserType
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }    
    [ForeignKey("TrackingInfo")]
    public long ObjectID { get; set; }

    public virtual Core_TrackingInfo TrackingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I have excluded some of the code for brevity, but the key property is `TrackingInfo`. This entity (and the entire code first entity model are in a class library called EntityModel.

The solution has 2 web application projects (both ASP.Net MVC), both of which reference this class library.

In the library itself there is some code that inserts a few entries, one of which is a new `Core_UserType`. When called from application A this runs perfectly. The problem is when called from project B, the code fails (after inserting some other objects OK) with:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

And an inner exception:

> Invalid column name TrackingInfo_ID

I dug a little deeper into the stack track and found that project B is trying to execute this SQL:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Core_UserType]([Name], [ObjectID], [TrackingInfo_ID])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2)
SELECT [ID]
FROM [dbo].[Core_UserType]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID] = scope_identity()
```

Obviously `TrackingInfo_ID` doesn't exist (it should be using `ObjectID`) so it fails.

The question is why is project A able to honour the `ForeignKey` attribute and project B isn't?

Comment: Can you show your definition for Core_TrackingInfo?  I suspect you're trying to create a 1:1 or 1:0..1 relationship, and you can't do that this way.

Comment: Yes it's used like a 1:1 but defined as a 1:many. The Core_TrackingInfo side has this: `public virtual ICollection<Core_UserType> Core_UserTypes { get; set; }`. Crucially though this all works fine from project A so I don't think there is anything wrong with the model itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do this the opposite way: This means the ForeignKey DataAnnotaion on the other property:

```
public long ObjectID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ObjectID")]
public virtual Core_TrackingInfo TrackingInfo { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not true.  You can specify it either way.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx   `The annotation may be placed on the foreign key property and specify the associated navigation property name, or placed on a navigation property and specify the associated foreign key name`

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Thanks for clearify. But I suspect, that this would help to solve the problem of the OP, because obviously it has interpreted the `TrackingInfo` as it's own ForeignKey and used the automagic generated `TrackingInfo_ID`.

Comment: I doubt it will make any difference, as I suspect he's probably trying to create a 1:1 relationship, which can't be done this way.

Comment: I can't believe that worked! I was as skeptical as @ErikFunkenbusch thinking it wouldn't make any difference but it totally worked. Thanks!

Comment: @BenC3 - Hmm.. My guess then is that it was probably something that got regenerated by moving it to the other property.  I'd bet if you moved it back, it would still work.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Out of interest's sake I tried putting it back the other way and cleaning/rebuilding but the problem reappears. My guess is some obscure bug in EF that is somehow brought on by this particular setup.